# LESS: Applying a ruleset only when selector is in another selector

Tags: css, less

Say I've got:

```
.apple {
    color: red;
}
```

Now, let's say I've also got:

```
.big {
    .apple {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can put the `.big` selector inside the rule for `.apple`? In psuedocode, something like:

```
.apple {
    color: red;

    &:[WHEN INSIDE `.big`] {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah, seconds after posting this: /just found/ http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature

Comment: Welp. Just answered it then caught your comment.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks! Appreciate it. That section was all the way at the bottom :D

Comment: Yeah... it looks like the documentation for that feature was much improved from the last time I read it though.

Comment: @BoltClock the irony, really, is that I hadn't realized `&:hover` is the exact same syntatic usage. Very straight forward. And `&:extend(.inline)` is at the top for some reason. Another exact same useage? The token always means the "parents", or "current selector scope" in other words?

Comment: I guess you could say that it represents the selector in the parent scope, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You place the `&` at the end:

```
.apple {
    color: red;

    .big & {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}
```